# Logic using cURL, PHP and Twitter without using API

Tags: php, curl, twitter

I have this code, which saves the `cookies` in a `.txt` file, and authenticates the user with Twitter

```
<?php

require_once 'class/Cookies.php';

$cookie = [];

$username = 'formUser';
$password = 'formPass';

$index_url = 'https://twitter.com';

$token = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($token, [
      CURLOPT_URL             => $index_url,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
      //CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cookies' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $username . '.txt',
      CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cookies' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $username . '.txt',
      CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION   => true,
      CURLOPT_REFERER         => $index_url,
      CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => ['Cookie:' . http_build_query($cookie, '', ';') . ';'],
      CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => function ($curl, $header) use (&$cookie) {
        if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0) {
          if (preg_match('/Set-Cookie:\s?(.*?)=(.*?);/i', $header, $matches)) {
            $cookie[$matches[1]] = urldecode($matches[2]);
          }
        }
        return strlen($header);
      }
    ]
);    
$access = curl_exec($token);

preg_match('/value="(.*?)" name="authenticity_token"/', $access, $matches);

$authenticity_token = $matches[1];

//var_dump($authenticity_token);

$session_post = "session[username_or_email]=$username&session[password]=$password&return_to_ssl=true&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=%2F&authenticity_token=$authenticity_token";



$session_url = 'https://twitter.com/sessions';

curl_setopt_array($token, [
      CURLOPT_URL             => $session_url,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $session_post,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => [
        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'Cookie: '. http_build_query($cookie, '', ';').';'
      ],
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
      CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 2,
      CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS,
      CURLOPT_POSTREDIR       => 2,
      CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER     => 1
  ]

);
$auth = curl_exec($token);

var_dump($cookie);

if (isset($cookie['auth_token']))
{
  $twid = filter_var($cookie['twid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

  Cookies::set('login_token', $cookie['ct0']);
  Cookies::set('kdt', $cookie['kdt']);
  Cookies::set('user_id', $twid);
  Cookies::set('auth_token', $cookie['auth_token']);
  Cookies::set('username', $username);


  echo json_encode(array(
    "status"      => "success",
    "message"     => "Authentication successful, we are redirecting you.",
  ));
}
else
{
  echo json_encode(
    array(
      "status" => "error",
      'message'=> "Unable to authenticate with Twitter.",
    ));
}
```

And this code that captures the information of the logged in user:

```
<?php

$username = 'sessionUser';

$url = 'https://twitter.com/' . $username;

$user = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($user, [
      CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_CAINFO          => 'cacert-2017-06-07.pem',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => [
        "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8",
      ],
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
      CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 2,
      CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS,
      CURLOPT_POSTREDIR       => 2,
      CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER     => 1,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING        => "gzip"
  ]
);

$user_info = curl_exec($user);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($user, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($user_info, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($user_info, $header_size);

$dom = new DOMDocument("5.0", "utf-8");
@$dom->loadHTML($body);

$data = json_decode($dom->getElementById("init-data")->getAttribute("value"));

echo "Nome: ", $data->profile_user->id, PHP_EOL;
echo "Nome: ", $data->profile_user->name, PHP_EOL;
echo "Usuário: ", $data->profile_user->screen_name, PHP_EOL;
echo "Foto de perfil: ", $data->profile_user->profile_image_url, PHP_EOL;
```

I need help so that the cookies of users saved in the .txt or in the database, make followers exchange.

**How can I do this?**

**EDIT**

Who downvote, leave comments.

**EDIT 2**

File `follow.php`

```
<?php

require_once '../modules/config.php';
require_once '../modules/class/Cookies.php';


$username = Cookies::get('username');

$friend_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json';

$friend = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($friend, [
        CURLOPT_URL             => $friend_url,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
        CURLOPT_CAINFO          => ROOT . 'modules' . SEPARATOR . 'cacert' . SEPARATOR . 'cacert-2017-06-07.pem',
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => 'screen_name=' . $username,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => [
            "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
      ],
        CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
    ]

);

$response  = curl_exec($friend);

var_dump($response);
```

Response:

```
C:\wamp64\www\brfollow\api\follow.php:32:string 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
content-length: 62
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Fri, 07 Jul 2017 08:09:54 GMT
server: tsa_d
set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A149941499419523606; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 07-Jul-2019 08:09:54 UTC
strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
x-connection-hash: 9e951d1215095efa246c5b852acd2e8a
x-response-time: 131
x-tsa-request-body-time: 0

{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}' (length=472)
```

Comment: why are you not using the API, do you know your breaching twitters terms but not using the API ?

Comment: So you're asking how to save the information that you have extracted into either a database or a `.txt` document? You would need MySQL to save to a database. You're also breaching the ToS of Twitter by not using their API to extract their data.

Comment: Yes, but with API it's complicated to do what I want, and I doubt there's anyone here using pirated OS, so I do not want any help with logic.

Comment: this API is MUCH simpler than this code.

Comment: @rtfm 
Yes, but using the API is almost impossible to do followers exchange

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: @SagarV 
For now, I need help with logic for users to follow without using the API

Comment: what does `followers exchange` mean?

Comment: Self follow bro "exchange"

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by `self follow bro "exchange"`, either. do you mean you want to follow everyone who already follows you?

Comment: @rtfm the usual reason for doing this, is that he's trying to do something the api doesn't support. - that said, i don't understand what he's trying to do in the first place, so i don't know

Comment: @hanshenrik yes, bro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first some notes on your existing code: 
don't use CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST for `GET` and `POST` requests. for `GET`, use `CURLOPT_HTTPGET=>true` (also note that GET is the default request for libcurl), and for `POST` requests, use `CURLOPT_POST=>true`.

this line `preg_match('/value="(.*?)" name="authenticity_token"/', $access, $matches);`
will break if they put any additional properties between the value and the name, 
and it will even break if they just move the name behind the value, and it will break
 if they put a simmilar string in a comment (`<!-- -->`-style), and it will even break if they just put another space between value and name, 
  [and parsing HTML with regex is generally a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1067003)

a much more robust approach would be:

```
$authenticity_token=(new DOMXpath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($access)))->query("//input[@name='authenticity_token']")->item(0)->getAttribute("value");
```

in this line, you do the same mistake 3 times:

```
$session_post = "session[username_or_email]=$username&session[password]=$password&return_to_ssl=true&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=%2F&authenticity_token=$authenticity_token";
```

you don't urlencode $username , $password, and $authenticity_token . that means, if any of those 3 contains any characters with special meaning in `application/x-www-urlencoded` format, the server will get the wrong data (this includes spaces, `&`, `=`, `[`,`Æ`,`Ø`,`Å`, and a lot of other characters), the easy solution is to use urlencode() on them - and the pretty solution is to use http_build_query to make the string, like this:

```
$session_post = http_build_query ( array (
        'session' => array (
                'username_or_email' => $username,
                'password' => $password 
        ),
        'return_to_sssl' => true,
        'scribe_log' => '',
        'redirect_after_login' => '/',
        'authenticity_token' => $authenticity_token 
) );
```

also you make the same mistake on this line:

```
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => 'screen_name=' . $username,
```

and this line must have been added by mistake:

```
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => [
    "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8",
  ],
```

it is a GET request with no request body, thus there is no `content-type`, because there is no content, so there's no way that content-type header declaration is supposed to be there, get rid of it.

this line

```
  CURLOPT_ENCODING        => "gzip"
```

will break your code if curl was not compiled with gzip, and the server actually decide to use gzip (more specifically, you will get unintelligible binary data), and you provide no code to actually handle gzip binary data. a much more robust approach is to set it to emptystring `""`, then curl will provide all encodings that libcurl was compiled will, and will de-encode it for you on the fly (including gzip, if compiled in. its usually `gzip` and `deflate`, but its also future-proof because it will add any future encodings automatically)

this line

```
    "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
```

don't add this header automatically. libcurl will automatically detect `application/x-www-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` encodings, and set the appropriate `content-type` headers automatically. and unlike you, libcurl won't make typos in doing so.

now, the next step is to get all your current followers, and send a follow request. you say you don't want to use the api, but THERE IS LITERALLY NO WAY to avoid it (short of hacking the twitter databases, ofc), even tiwtter's javascript's "follow" button uses the api. good news is, you can get away by using twitter's javascript's api token, and thus not having to use your own token. this may sound easy in theory, but its really not. never the less, here's an example implementation with hhb_curl (from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php ), getting a list of your followers, and sending a follow request to each one, using twitters own api key (extracted automatically):

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');
const USERNAME = '???';
const PASSWORD = '???';

$hc = new hhb_curl ( 'https://twitter.com/login', true );
$hc->exec ();
// get csrf token
$csrf_token = [ ];
preg_match ( '/\s+ct0\s*=\s*(.*?)\;/', implode ( "\n", $hc->getResponseHeaders () ), $csrf_token );
if (count ( $csrf_token ) !== 2) {
    throw new Exception ( 'failed to extract the csrf token!' );
}
$csrf_token = $csrf_token [1];
// to log in...

$html = $hc->getStdOut ();
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
$inputs = getDOMDocumentFormInputs ( $domd, true ) [0]; // << not sure why, but they have 6 seemingly duplicate login forms. the first 1 works fine.
$inputs = DOMInputsToArray ( $inputs );
$inputs ['session[username_or_email]'] = USERNAME;
$inputs ['session[password]'] = PASSWORD;
// hhb_var_dump ( $inputs ) & die ();
$html = $hc->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( $inputs ),
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://twitter.com/sessions' 
) )->exec ()->getResponseBody ();
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
$xpath = new DOMXPath ( $domd );
// hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getStdOut () );
if (false !== stripos ( $hc->getinfo ( CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL ), 'login/error' )) {
    throw new Exception ( 'failed to login!' );
}
echo "logged in!", PHP_EOL;
// now to get the api key
$js = $hc->exec ( 'https://abs.twimg.com/k/en/init.en.c5a67fc1f42cedcdbbcd.js' )->getResponseBody ();
// hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getStdOut () ) & die ();
// fragile regex: assumes that there's only 1x i="114 characters"; , and that the api key is exactly 114 characters.
preg_match ( '/i\s*\=\s*\"([^\"]{114})\"\s*\;/iu', $js, $matches );
// hhb_var_dump ( $matches ) & die ();
if (count ( $matches ) !== 2) {
    throw new RuntimeException ( 'failed to extract the api auth key!' );
}
$api_auth_key = $matches [1];

$myurl = 'https://twitter.com/' . ltrim ( $xpath->query ( '//a[contains(@class,\'DashboardProfileCard\')]' )->item ( 0 )->getAttribute ( "href" ), '/' );
echo 'myurl: ' . $myurl . PHP_EOL;
// $myurl = 'https://twitter.com/scaleway';
$myurl .= '/followers';
$html = $hc->exec ( $myurl )->getResponseBody ();
// hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getStdOut () ) & die ();
$toFollow = array ();
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
$xpath = new DOMXPath ( $domd );
foreach ( $xpath->query ( '//div[contains(@class,\'ProfileCard-content\')]' ) as $followerDiv ) {
    $name = $xpath->query ( './/*[@data-screen-name]', $followerDiv )->item ( 0 )->getAttribute ( "data-screen-name" );
    $user_id = $xpath->query ( './/*[@data-user-id]', $followerDiv )->item ( 0 )->getAttribute ( "data-user-id" );
    echo "following " . $name . ' (' . $user_id . ')' . PHP_EOL;
    try {
        $hc->setopt_array ( array (
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'OPTIONS',
                CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json',
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                        'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST',
                        'Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,x-csrf-token,x-twitter-active-user,x-twitter-auth-type',
                        'DNT: 1',
                        'Origin: https://twitter.com' 
                ) 
        ) )->exec ();
    } catch ( Throwable $ex ) {
        // there is a bug where it sometimes respond http 200 OK, but with 0 bytes content. hhb_curl doesn't like this, as 0-bytes-responses should actually be http 201.
        // feel free to contact twitter with a bugreport.
    }
    // hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr () );
    $hc->setopt ( CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, NULL );
    $hc->setopt_array ( array (
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( array (
                    'challenges_passed' => 'false',
                    'handles_challenges' => '1',
                    'impression_id' => '',
                    'include_blocked_by' => 'true',
                    'include_blocking' => 'true',
                    'include_can_dm' => 'true',
                    'include_followed_by' => 'true',
                    'include_mute_edge' => 'true',
                    'skip_status' => 'true',
                    'user_id' => $user_id 
            ) ),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                    'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
                    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $api_auth_key,
                    'x-twitter-auth-type: OAuth2Session',
                    'x-csrf-token: ' . $csrf_token,
                    'X-Twitter-Active-User: yes',
                    'DNT: 1',
                    'Origin: https://twitter.com',
                    'Referer: ' . $myurl 

            ) 

    ) )->exec ();

    // parse_str ( $hc->getopt ( CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ), $fields );
    // hhb_var_dump ( $fields, $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getStdOut () ) & die ();
}

// hhb_var_dump ( $myurl );
function DOMInputsToArray($inputs): array {
    $ret = [ ];
    foreach ( $inputs as $in ) {
        if ($in->hasAttribute ( "disabled" )) {
            continue;
        }
        $name = $in->getAttribute ( "name" );
        if (empty ( $name )) {
            continue;
        }
        $ret [$name] = $in->getAttribute ( "value" );
    }
    return $ret;
}
function getDOMDocumentFormInputs(\DOMDocument $domd, bool $getOnlyFirstMatches = false): array {
    // :DOMNodeList?
    $forms = $domd->getElementsByTagName ( 'form' );
    $parsedForms = array ();
    $isDescendantOf = function (\DOMNode $decendant, \DOMNode $ele): bool {
        $parent = $decendant;
        while ( NULL !== ($parent = $parent->parentNode) ) {
            if ($parent === $ele) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
    // i can't use array_merge on DOMNodeLists :(
    $merged = function () use (&$domd): array {
        $ret = array ();
        foreach ( $domd->getElementsByTagName ( "input" ) as $input ) {
            $ret [] = $input;
        }
        foreach ( $domd->getElementsByTagName ( "textarea" ) as $textarea ) {
            $ret [] = $textarea;
        }
        return $ret;
    };
    $merged = $merged ();
    foreach ( $forms as $form ) {
        $inputs = function () use (&$domd, &$form, &$isDescendantOf, &$merged): array {
            $ret = array ();
            foreach ( $merged as $input ) {
                // hhb_var_dump ( $input->getAttribute ( "name" ), $input->getAttribute ( "id" ) );
                if ($input->hasAttribute ( "disabled" )) {
                    // ignore disabled elements?
                    continue;
                }
                $name = $input->getAttribute ( "name" );
                if ($name === '') {
                    // echo "inputs with no name are ignored when submitted by mainstream browsers (presumably because of specs)... follow suite?", PHP_EOL;
                    continue;
                }
                if (! $isDescendantOf ( $input, $form ) && $form->getAttribute ( "id" ) !== '' && $input->getAttribute ( "form" ) !== $form->getAttribute ( "id" )) {
                    // echo "this input does not belong to this form.", PHP_EOL;
                    continue;
                }
                if (! array_key_exists ( $name, $ret )) {
                    $ret [$name] = array (
                            $input 
                    );
                } else {
                    $ret [$name] [] = $input;
                }
            }
            return $ret;
        };
        $inputs = $inputs (); // sorry about that, Eclipse gets unstable on IIFE syntax.
        $hasName = true;
        $name = $form->getAttribute ( "id" );
        if ($name === '') {
            $name = $form->getAttribute ( "name" );
            if ($name === '') {
                $hasName = false;
            }
        }
        if (! $hasName) {
            $parsedForms [] = array (
                    $inputs 
            );
        } else {
            if (! array_key_exists ( $name, $parsedForms )) {
                $parsedForms [$name] = array (
                        $inputs 
                );
            } else {
                $parsedForms [$name] [] = $tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    unset ( $form, $tmp, $hasName, $name, $i, $input );
    if ($getOnlyFirstMatches) {
        foreach ( $parsedForms as $key => $val ) {
            $parsedForms [$key] = $val [0];
        }
        unset ( $key, $val );
        foreach ( $parsedForms as $key1 => $val1 ) {
            foreach ( $val1 as $key2 => $val2 ) {
                $parsedForms [$key1] [$key2] = $val2 [0];
            }
        }
    }
    return $parsedForms;
}
```

output:
`logged in!
myurl: https://twitter.com/HansHenrik_
following tianwm (53056654)
following theburakcinar (2335591322)
following DnR_iData (260134525)
following 7wData (1713417312)
following deepudeepana (783199483404226560)
following remco_verhoef (201001391)
following PaulVlasin (1079477118)
^C`

(i manually canceled it at ^C, as i dont want to follow everyone, but it was enough to prove that it worked) - and don't forget to replace username/password on line 4 & line 5 - and note that since i don't have any followers, i used https://twitter.com/scaleway/followers as a test page with lots of followers, you can see where i faked the url at the commented-out line 50. - also, it will probably just send a request to all the followers you can see on the followers page, which, if you have a lot of followers, is not the full list (this would crash your browser etc), so you'll have to find out how to get the full list of followers if you have a big amount of followers -

Comment: Dude, I tested it and it's really what I wanted, you're awesome! Anything I comment on.

Comment: Now, I wanted the reverse, like, all the IDs or Tokens saved in the bank, if they follow, that is: every 5 that I follow, I get 10 followers, understand? it's possible?

Comment: @WillBB not sure what you mean. do you mean: `you want to wait for your account to get 10 followers, and when you do, you want to follow 5 of those 10 new followers` ?

Comment: Example: Everyone logging in will save the ID in a database, it will be follower exchange. I still have 5 gain 10, but only the IDs that are in the database.

Comment: **Summarizing** : I'm follow 5 I get 10

Comment: @WillBB it is possible to follow 5, and wait for 10 new followers, and repeat - but how to do that, should be in its own dedicated question - not in the comments of this question.

Comment: Okay, I'll open a new question later, I'll get a reputation so I can offer. Can you help me?

Comment: @WillBB usually, you only need a bounty if your question is particularly difficult to answer

Comment: Okay, I'll go and open it and I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use

```
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cookies' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $username . '.txt',
```

in your second request too.

Comment: Okay, but I need help with logic to make the follower exchange. I'm going to edit the topic with my follow.php file, I'm not using OAuth, and I need to generate an access token. Could you help me?

Comment: This is just a solution to your original question. If you want to to something more advanced then just reading some HTML you have to use API.

Comment: Several sites the same I want to do, do not use API.

Answer (score 1):

This is against Twitter's developer policy and your application and IP risk being banned from the platform. Furthermore, Twitter's rules explicitly prohibit the kind of application you are building - see https://support.twitter.com/articles/20171936

Comment: I'm not doing it anymore